# Azure Overlapped Recycling is not working

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, ravendb

I have an azure web site i created to test azure and a web site. So far I like azure but i've run into a problem.

I am trying to run RavenDB embedded database in my website, as I'm not yet ready to get a full database.
RavenDB requires that the app pool is set to Disable Overlapped Recycle.
I followed the steps from this stack overflow article to achieve that:

[Disable pool recycling on Azure Websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421024/how-to-disable-overlapped-recycle-on-azure-websites)

When I download the applicationHost.config file i can see the line:

<recycling disallowOverlappingRotation="true" />

Which tells me the overlapped recycling should be disabled.

But i am still getting errors with my ravenDB database, which relates to the overlapped recycling.

Is there any other way to confirm that overlapped recycling is disabled or be able to modify my azure app pool. Without having to get a full support plan or something like that?

My application is Microsoft.Owin, so there is no global.asax or app_start folder. There is a startup class.