# How to share a Semaphore across 2 w3wp.exe IIS processes

Tags: azure, iis, semaphore, w3wp

How do I create a semaphore that is accessible across 2 separate w3wp.exe processes on Azure.
The problem on Azure is that when a new application configuration item is added Azure restarts my website on a new w3wp.exe process that is running concurrently with the old w3wp.exe process while it is shutting down. I use a semaphore to synchronize between the 2. This has worked well up until now i.e. On local IIS - config changes normally just start a new app domain, but on Azure a new w3wp.exe process is started. And this new process does not recognise an existing named semaphore.

The following code always indicates the semaphore does not exist. Even when I create a standalone console app and create the semaphore - I still get it does not exist in my web app. There seems to be a namespace in play for semaphores in IIS on Azure. I had seen another post on an early version of IIS that semaphores only became globally shared across processes if they had "Global\" as a name prefix - this does not work on Azure and I can't find out what the "global" namespace should be - any ideas?

FYI - If I run a console application - 2 instances - that both access the same semaphore they can both see it. But 2 processes running in IIS on Azure cannot.

```
try
{
    // Open the semaphore 
    //
    _semaphore2 = Semaphore.OpenExisting(name);
    doesNotExist = false;
}
catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
{
    _logger.Info<MainDom>("Semaphore ({name}) does not exist", name);
    doesNotExist = true;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a named mutex, which is machine wide, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it was a good thought. However on Azure 2 w3wp processes do not see a named mutex created by the other process even if the name has the "Global\" prefix.  Using the overload that advises if the mutex was createdNew - both processes report that they both created it new.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of spawning a new worker process is called overlapped recycling.  You can disable this behavior and allow for the worker process to shut down completely before the new process is started.  You can even disable recycling on configuration change.

For local IIS, modify the advanced properties of the app pool and configure the **Disable Overlapped Recycle** and/or **Disable Recycling for Configuration Changes** options.  I believe the latter is only available in IIS 10+.

[image: Configure Applcation Pool]

The process for Azure is a bit trickier.  It involves updating the applicationHost.config for which you need to use Kudu.  See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421024/disable-pool-recycling-on-azure-websites) for detailed instructions.

Essentially, it involves creating an XDT (transform) file to update the config file.  An example can be found:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#remove-all-your-recycling-options-from-your-net-4-application-pool-and-make-it-available-always

Edit:

If the above does not prevent two worker processes running concurrently, you may also need to configure the **Shutdown Time Limit**.  In the transform file, include the second line in the following block:

```
<add name="yourAppPoolNameHere" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
    <processModel shutdownTimeLimit="00:00:01" />
```

Word of caution, the above will result in svchost.exe killing the w3wp.exe process after 1 second without any grace.

Comment: Thank you - that was a good suggestion and if i could make sure on recycle that 1 w3wp process was completely closed down before the other one spun up - that would have worked for me. However, after making the changes on Azure I found that the 2 w3wp process were still running concurrently - I did verify that the applicationhost.config changes were done - see next comment where disallowOverlappingRotation is present in https://johnblair.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LocalSiteRoot/Config/applicationhost.config

Comment: <applicationPools>
      <add name="johnblair" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
        <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" />
        <recycling disallowOverlappingRotation="true" />
      </add>
      <add name="~1johnblair" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
        <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" />
        <recycling disallowOverlappingRotation="true" />
      </add>
    </applicationPools>

Comment: The reason i knew my 2 w3wp processes were running concurrently was that my log files had intermittent wrties after making a config change.

Comment: Just in case editing the .config file directly doesn't work, please see my edit and linked example of using an XDT transform file :)

Comment: Thanks I used the XDT transform file and used the api url https://johnblair.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LocalSiteRoot/Config/applicationhost.config to verify the disallowOverlappingRotation setting was present in the config file - which it was. However, after a couple of app restarts in azure - just to make sure - and making a config change to trigger a w3wp process cycle - i noticed in my log file log messages from 2 processes - indicating the second one had started up before the first one had completely finished - which i didn't think would happen with this setting. The transform worked.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">>
  <system.applicationHost>
    <applicationPools>
      <add name="johnblair" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <recycling disallowOverlappingRotation="true" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
      </add>
      <add name="~1johnblair" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <recycling disallowOverlappingRotation="true" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
      </add>
    </applicationPools>
  </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>

Comment: Previous comment was my applicationHost.xdt file and placed in the parent directory of the website. The config download url showed the transform had been actioned.

Comment: Can you try the last suggestion in my updated answer?

Comment: I don't like the sound of that change. I need to perform a controlled shutdown as I close file handles and other tidying up. I can't risk a random termination. I don't see how that would affect concurrency except for limiting the amount of concurrent time to max of 1 second. I don't know why the 2nd process is starting up ...its as if IIS is not honouring the disallowOverlappingRotation parameter.

Comment: It may be auto start or preload settings overriding it.  I can reproduce it on my local machine.  If you need to tidy up on shutdown and you know it will be less than say 10 seconds, you could put a sleep in your startup before you attempt to open the semaphore - `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);`

Comment: That's an interesting thought - include a delay - I'll try it out. The site does get preloaded i.e. a dummy request to localhost to warm it up.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work - I'm still researching why. The longer I delayed the new process the longer it took the shutting down process to shutdown - weird - something for tomorrow! Thanks for the suggestion it should have worked.

Comment: FYI to my surprise  Setting WEBSITE_DISABLE_OVERLAPPED_RECYCLING to 1 in the Azure Application Settings worked in terms of serializing the w3wp processes - all logging happened for only 1 process at a time - even though the config transform did not show this behaviour! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the update John.  Seems this was added to Kudu in May 2018.  I'll investigate if the XDT file is even effective any more.  It would appear it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround - not an answer - but posting it here in case it helps others - as it is buried in one of my comments which is hidden by default.

Setting WEBSITE_DISABLE_OVERLAPPED_RECYCLING to 1 in the Azure Application Settings worked in terms of serializing the w3wp processes i.e. one would shutdown completely before the other started up - in my case this avoided the need for the semaphore. I would still like an answer to the original question.